# javascript prototype method

Tags: javascript, prototype

Simple javascript program to show which rectangle has bigger perimeter when button is clicked, but **Rectangle.Perimeter** doesn't seem to get the needed value from the **Rectangle** object for width and height. It just prints NaN instead of the perimeter.

```
<script>
    function Rectangle(width, height) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }
    var Rectangle1 = new Rectangle(2, 4);
    var Rectangle2 = new Rectangle(8.5, 11);

     Rectangle.prototype.PrintRectangle = function () {
        document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = "Rectangle width is " + this.width + " and Rectangle height is "+ this.height;
    };
    Rectangle.prototype.RectanglePerimeter = this.width*2 + this.height*2;


    function calculate() {
        if(Rectangle1.RectanglePerimeter > Rectangle2.RectanglePerimeter){
            document.getElementById("perimetar").innerHTML = "The biggest Rectangle has perimeter of " + Rectangle1.RectanglePerimeter;
        }else{
            document.getElementById("perimetar").innerHTML = "The biggest Rectangle has perimeter of " + Rectangle2.RectanglePerimeter;
        }
    }

</script>

<body>
<p><b>Paragraph no: 1</b></p>
<p id="p1" onload="Rectangle1.PrintRectangle()"></p>
<button id="button" onclick="calculate()">Calculate Perimeter</button>
<p id="perimetar"></p>
</body>
```

Comment: When you create `Rectangle.prototype.RectanglePerimeter`, what does `this` refer to?

Comment: I think you meant to make `RectanglePerimeter` a function.

Comment: The thing is, when I call Rectangle1.RectanglePerimeter I want it to refer to Rectangle1's width and height called from here 
var Rectangle1 = new Rectangle(2, 4);
Apparently I dont know how to do that :))

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
Rectangle.prototype.getPerimeter = function() { 
    return this.width*2 + this.height*2;
};
```

and then use

```
if(Rectangle1.getPerimeter() > Rectangle2.getPerimeter())
```

Comment: This works but the actual problem in my code was the fact that my functions name starts with a capital letter?! As soon as I changed 
Rectangle.prototype.RectanglePerimeter = this.width*2 + this.height*2;

Comment: This works, but the actual problem in my code was the fact that the functions name started with a capital letter.
I just changed 
Rectangle.prototype.RectanglePerimeter = this.width*2 + this.height*2;
to 
Rectangle.prototype.rectanglePerimeter = this.width*2 + this.height*2;
and it started working.......... Somehow this cannot get reffered to the object if the objects function starts with a Capital Letter

Comment: just replace `Rectangle.prototype.getPerimeter` with your original name: `Rectangle.prototype.RectanglePerimeter`